# QNetworkReply returning incomplete XML data

Tags: c++, xml, qt, http-get, qnetworkreply

I'm sending a HTTP GET request to a remote server. Using various parameters I define the content I'm interested in. In particular I make sure that `output=xml` is in the query since it makes the server return a reply as XML.

I have the following connections between my class `HttpRetriever` and the respective `QNetworkReply` and `QNetworkAccessManager` (for the `QNetworkRequest` see **slotStartRequest()**):

```
connect(this->reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this,
        SLOT(slotErrorRequest(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
connect(this->reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &HttpRetriever::slotFinishRequest);
connect(this->manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this->reply, &QNetworkReply::deleteLater);
connect(this->reply, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &HttpRetriever::slotReadyReadRequest);
```

The slots that are of interest here have the following declaration:

**slotFinishRequest():**

```
void HttpRetriever::slotFinishRequest()
{
    LOG(INFO) << "Finishing HTTP GET request from URL \"" << this->url.toString() << "\"";
    this->reply = Q_NULLPTR;

    // Reset validity of reply from a previous request
    this->validReply = false;
    // Skip validation if it's disabled
    if (!this->validateReply)
    {
        LOG(WARNING) << "Validation disabled. In order to enable it see the \"validate\" and \"validationMode\" in \"settings.ini\"";
        this->validReply = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Validate reply
        this->validReply = validateReply();
    }

    if (!this->validReply)
    {
        return;
    }

    processReply(); // Parsing

    this->processingRequest = false;
}
```

**slotReadyReadRequest():**

```
void HttpRetriever::slotReadyReadRequest()
{
    LOG(INFO) << "Received data from \"" << this->url.toString() << "\"";
    this->bufferReply = this->reply->readAll();
}
```

Inside the `slotFinishRequest()` I call the `processReply()`:

```
void HttpRetriever::processReply()
{
    LOG(INFO) << "Processing reply for request \"" << this->url.toString() << "\"";
    LOG(DEBUG) << QString(this->bufferReply);
    // Process the XML from the reply and extract necessary data

    QXmlStreamReader reader;
    reader.addData(this->bufferReply);

    // Read the XML reply and extract required data
    // TODO
    while (!reader.atEnd())
    {
        LOG(DEBUG) << "Reading XML element";
        reader.readNextStartElement();

        QXmlStreamAttributes attributes = reader.attributes();
        foreach (QXmlStreamAttribute attrib, attributes)
        {
            LOG(DEBUG) << attrib.name();
        }
    }
    if (reader.hasError())
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Encountered error while parsing XML data:" << reader.errorString();
    }

    LOG(INFO) << "Sending data to data fusion handler";
    // TODO
}
```

I trigger the HTTP get request through the following slot:

```
void HttpRetriever::slotStartRequest(quint32 id)
{
    if (this->processingRequest)
    {
        this->reply->abort();
    }

    this->processingRequest = false;

    // The first request also instantiates the manager. If the slot is called after the instance of HafasHttpRetriever
    // is moved to a new thread this will ensure proper parenting
    if (!this->manager)
    {
        this->manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    }

    quint32 requestId = generateRequestId(stopId);
    if (!this->url.hasQuery())
    {
        LOG(WARNING) << "Attempting to start request without parameters";
    }

    // Part of the filters applied to the request to reduce the data received (for more see slotSetRequestParams())
    QUrlQuery query(this->url.query());
    query.addQueryItem("input", QString::number(requestId));
    // TODO Add more filters; see documentation

    this->url.setQuery(query);

    LOG(INFO) << "Requesting data from \"" << this->url.toString() << "\" with request ID:" << requestId;

    QNetworkRequest request(this->url);
    this->reply = this->manager->get(request);

    // Establish connections from/to the reply and the network access manager
    connect(this->reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this,
            SLOT(slotErrorRequest(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
    connect(this->reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &HttpRetriever::slotFinishRequest);
    connect(this->manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this->reply, &QNetworkReply::deleteLater);
    connect(this->reply, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &HttpRetriever::slotReadyReadRequest);
}
```

As you can see so far I have laid down the foundation for the network communication between my class and the server and I am yet to start working on the parsing of the XML reply and extracting the information I need from it.

The problem is that I am getting (very, very often) either

> Encountered error while parsing XML data: Start tag expected.

or

> Encountered error while parsing XML data: Premature end of document

in my `processReply()` function. This happens every time I get a large reply (a couple of hundreds up to a couple of thousands of lines). It never happens when I get a small one (30-40 lines give or take).

So the issue is obviously somewhere in the amount of data I am receiving, the way it is put together by the `QNetworkAccessManager` (or whichever Qt component in all this buffers the received chunks of data) and/or perhaps the way I have setup the instances of the network-related components in my class. I also have to make an important note here namely that in my browser (latest Firefox with the **HttpRequester** add-on) I am always receiving the complete XML no matter how large it is. So this seems to be a problem exclusive to my application and has nothing to do with the network settings on my system.

Comment: I suspect the problem is here:  this->bufferReply = this->reply->readAll(); you should not assign but append, and then when you process the buffer clean it.

Comment: Indeed, now I'm getting plenty of data. However I still get the `Encountered error while parsing XML data: Premature end of document` error. I've look at the output in my browser and the output in Qt and there doesn't seem to be a missing tag (root tag is closed at the end).

Comment: I think I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354587/1559401). Will give it a go and comment here if it works so that you can post a more complete answer for me to mark as such.

Comment: Yeap, it fixed the issue. Please post an answer (including a link to the one I posted in my previous comment). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @Marco didn't write the answer...

The problem was that I was rewriting my buffer all the time by assigning the result from `QNetworkReply::readAll()`. As suggested using `QByteArray::append()` solves the problem.

In order to prevent a possible issue from this solution namely that you keep appending with each and every next reply you get, `QByteArray::clear()` needs to be called at some point for example when the `finished()` signal is emitted. Of course one needs to first process its contents before flushing it down the drain.